# Installing Ubuntu One in Windows 7 - hangs at "Getting information, please wait..."

Tags: installation, ubuntu-one, windows-7

I am making the switch from Dropbox to Ubuntu One (or, attempting to do so.) I have several machines with Ubuntu and Windows 7.

I have an Ubuntu One account, have added files from a couple Ubuntu machines, can access them on my Android devices, but have been unable to successfully install Ubuntu One on a Windows 7 computer. I have tried two, and on both the install process hangs at the "Getting information, please wait..." screen after I enter my credentials.

I have tried Google and searching here, but have not found a solution.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Machine Details:
Windows 7, 64 bit, fully updated
Avast Free A/V
Windows Firewall enabled (I tried letting Ubuntu One through, and this did not help.)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu one on windows 7 is really buggy.  I use Ubuntu 1 now and love it but too buggy on windows 7.  Use windows mesh instead.  It's free like Ubuntu 1 up to 5GB and even syncs removable devices.  Windows hotmail/live account required.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the feedback, Kris.  But, I need to sync files between a couple Ubuntu PC's and a couple W7 ones. I like the 5GBs of U1, and I like that it's Ubuntu-based.

Anyone have any other input on my problem?

Thanks.

Jeff